# Creating a dataframe from a nested list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that contains 10 lists, one for each participant. Within a list of a participant, there are anywhere between 1 and 20 values of type double. To clarify, this is the code to reproduce somehting similar to what I have:

```
Participant_List <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
  Scores <- list()
  for (k in sample(1:5, replace = TRUE)) {
    Scores[[k]] <- sample(1:7, sample(1:10), replace = TRUE)
  }
  Participant_List[[i]] <- Scores

}
```

I would like to create a loop where I add each participant's scores to a dataframe. This dataframe would store participants' scores in long format. So if a participant has 3 list entries, he gets 3 rows in the dataframe. I would also need an ID column.

| Participant | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.02 |
| 1 | 0.04 |
| 2 | 0.08 |
| 3 | 0.01 |
| 3 | 0.03 |
| 3 | 0.04 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a nested list of numeric vector, loop over the list with `map` and bind the inner list element with `bind_rows`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- map_dfr(lst1, ~ bind_rows(.x, .id = 'Participant'), .id = 'ID')
```

---

Or if the structure is different, try

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
map_dfr(lst1, ~ enframe(.x, name = 'Participant', value = 'Score') %>% 
     unnest(cols = Score), .id = 'ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting each participant's list to a data frame and then using `rbind` to combine them into one data frame. For example, if the list is stored in a variable named *Participant_List* :

```
#convert each participant's list to a data frame
x_dataframes <- lapply(seq_along(Participant_List), function(curParticipant){
   return(data.frame(Participant = curParticipant,
                     Score = unlist(Participant_List[[curParticipant]])))
})

#combine the list of dataframes into one dataframe
x_combined <- do.call("rbind", x_dataframes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure if this solution applies to the datastructre I have. I added a bit of code to simulate my situation.

Comment: It seems like you have one more level of complexity since each list in `Participant_List` is a list itself and not a vector. If I understood your goal correctly, then adding an `unlist` within the loop should handle that appropriately, assuming that you just want all the scores for each participant put together. I edited my answer accordingly. Hope you find that helpful!

Comment: Amazing! This worked! I am curious, how does the function know the value of "curParticipant"?

Comment: The `seq_along` function simply loops over the elements in `Participant_List` one-by-one, so its value is actually the index of the participant, i.e. the first participant has an index of 1 and so on.